# How to compile QEMU with SPICE support for macOS

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, qemu

To come somewhat close to the experience Parallels Desktop for Mac offers, I would like to run a Windows 10 virtual machine with the QXL graphics driver and SPICE support on a macOS host machine. Unfortunately neither the QEMU binary on [Homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/qemu) nor on [MacPorts](https://ports.macports.org/port/qemu/summary) offers SPICE support.

QEMU needs the spice-protocol and spice-server library to compile with SPICE support. While the [spice-protocol](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/spice-protocol) package is available for macOS, I can't seem to find a precompiled package of spice-server. As I tried to compile [spice-0.14.2](https://www.spice-space.org/download/releases/spice-server/) under macOS I encountered the following error:

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make  all-recursiveMaking all in .
  CC       red-stream.lo
  CC       red-worker.lo
red-worker.c:1164:40: error: too many arguments to function call, expected 1, have 2
    pthread_setname_np(worker->thread, "SPICE Worker");
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/pthread.h:512:1: note: 'pthread_setname_np' declared here
__API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.6), ios(3.2))
^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/Availability.h:496:162: note: expanded from macro '__API_AVAILABLE'
  ...__API_AVAILABLE6, __API_AVAILABLE5, __API_AVAILABLE4, __API_AVAILABLE3, __API_AVAILABLE2, __API_AVAILABLE1, 0)(__VA_ARGS__)
                                                                             ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: Seems to be solved by the following project: https://github.com/utmapp/UTM/blob/master/patches/spice-0.14.1.patch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research, it appears that on macOS `pthread_setname_np` can only be used to change the name of the calling thread.

From what I can tell this is only needed for debug purposes, and you can safely comment out the line when compiling for macOS. (You can also use conditional compilation, but there's no reason to if you're just trying to compile QEMU with SPICE support.)

---

Edit `server/red-worker.c` and comment out the following line:

```
pthread_setname_np(worker->thread, "SPICE Worker");
```

(I used nano. You can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> to search for `pthread_setname_np(`.)

---

Additional changes required to compile SPICE server for macOS (as of 0.14.3)

1. If you get the following error when running `./autogen.sh`:

   ```
   configure: error: Package requirements (openssl >= 1.0.0) were not met:

   No package 'openssl' found
   ```

   Then set the following environment variables:

   ```
   export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/pkgconfig"
   export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
   export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include"
   ```
2. Add the following line somewhere near the top of `server/red-stream.c` and `server/tests/test-websocket.c`:

   ```
   #define MSG_NOSIGNAL 0x2000 /* don't raise SIGPIPE */
   ```
3. In `server/tools/reds_stat.c` replace the following line:

   ```
   reds_stat = mremap(reds_stat, shm_old_size, shm_size, MREMAP_MAYMOVE);
   ```

   with:

   ```
   munmap(reds_stat, shm_old_size);
   reds_stat = mmap(0, shm_old_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, -1, 0);
   ```
4. If I didn't forget anything, all other errors can be "solved" by removing all occurrences of `-Werror` from the `Makefile`s.

Comment: Awesome! Were you able to compile QEMU with spice support and could to post the specific steps to reproduce?

Comment: @LauridsReichardt After removing a bunch of ```-Werror``` flags and replacing a call to ```mremap``` (doesn’t exist on Darwin systems) with something I found online that hopefully does the same thing, yes, I was able to get it to compile. I’ll post the details once I get back to my computer.

Comment: Fantastic work! Did you get QEMU to compile with SPICE support as well? Will try this evening.

Comment: @LauridsReichardt Yes, but so far using a remote viewer (either RemoteViewer for macOS from spice-space.org or spicy) is to slow to use. I get a screen refresh rate of 0.1-0.2Hz at best, and I can only move the mouse a few pixels/second.

Comment: Oh, that's disappointing. Are you running a Linux or Windows guest?

Comment: @LauridsReichardt Linux (so far I've only tried Lubuntu and Alpine (with XFCE4). (I've also tried spice side-by-side with a cocoa display, the latter works perfectly, spice is unbearable.) I'm still looking for a solution, I'll update if I find anything. Let me know if your results are different.

Comment: Seems to be solved inside the following project: https://github.com/utmapp/UTM/blob/master/patches/spice-0.14.1.patch